# connecting to heroku postgres locally doesn't work

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to connect to my heroku postgres db locally with python.
I have followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) tutorial.
I did `set DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)`, then in my python script ran `DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` but it gives an error 'KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL''.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it Powershell or WSL you're working in by chance? something's not working with the setting of the environment variable. there's a GUI-based way to do so in Windows, i don't know how the newer versions of Windows handle that, though. oh and just to be sure: you have installed Postgres server on your local machine, correct?

Comment: @mechanical_meat I am using powershell, and yes I have install postgres server on my local machine.

Comment: maybe look up how to set an environment variable in powershell in case it differs from the plain command line aka DOS.

Comment: @mechanical_meat I have tried to set it up at the cmd aswell and still did not work.